# MySQL Insert Ignore Into error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting a very odd error when I try to execute the following statement:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `INFORMATION` (`PRODUCT`, `CHARACTER`)
SELECT PRODUCTS.NAME, CHARACTERS.NAME FROM PRODUCTS, CHARACTERS
WHERE PRODUCTS.NAME='Beanie'
AND CHARACTERS.HAS_FULL_BEANIE=1;
```

If I run this statement, I get back Error #1442:

> Can't update table 'INFORMATION' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

This is bizarre, since I'm not running it in a trigger--I'm just running it as a query.

Executing the statement without 'ignore' yields the expected error due to a duplicate unique key.  The select statement run by itself produces the expected output that I want to insert.

I'm working through phpMyAdmin 3.5.5 on MySQL 5.5, since it's a hosted web account.

Comment: Are you sure that you have no insert trigger?

Comment: I was playing with a trigger earlier, but I dropped it and decided to pursue a different course when I couldn't make it do what I wanted.  phpMyAdmin does not show any existing triggers now.  Is there a SQL statement I can run to make it show me triggers that phpMyAdmin might be missing?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-triggers.html

Comment: In retrospect, I probably should have been able to find that on my own.  Running that turned up a trigger I thought I'd dropped still in existence.  After dropping it, the query I was trying to run worked as expected.  Thank you for the pointer.